# Prototype JS Override Data OnSubmit

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm trying to override some data via Prototope JS before submitting the form. How can I achieve it?

Here's the snippet:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('formId').observe('submit', function(e) {
    //override some field data here
    //before submitting
    //...
});
</script>
```

Comment: so you would change the form values?

Comment: @epascarello, yes. actually trying to modify or insert some values. I could have used hidden but i actually need to do some dynamic fields

Comment: Well you would need to change those dynamic elements... What is your problem exactly? There is no way to change the post data without changing the elements with a normal form submission.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you are picking the right event as the submit event fires before the submit takes place.

Here is a simple example that will change the value of the one input to all uppercase on submit

```
<form id="formId">
    <input type="text" name="forminput1" id="forminput1" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>


<script type='text/javascript'>
$('formId').observe('submit', function(e) {

    $('forminput1').value = $('forminput1').value.toUpperCase()

});
</script>
```

In general you can make any edits you want in the submit event handler as long as you can address the fields.